# Small computer that can run on power provided from CAT5e or USB?

Tags: hardware

I am wondering if such a thing exists. I am looking for a small computer (board, etc..) that I can literally just put a usb drive on in order to boot from, and then it get its power from USB or CAT5e. Any ideas?

Comment: Because there are so many possibilities, please tell us what you need it for. Does the screen have to be powered too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope out the [JackPC](http://www.chippc.com/products/jack-pc-lxj/). They run a RISC processor though, which may be limiting.

Comment: +1 - I love me some JackPC.

Comment: How is a RISC processor limiting?

Comment: The relative (to x86) lack of software is limiting.

Comment: It can't run full-blown windows and it needs a Linux distro compiled for it.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on to this post and noticed that the accepted answer's link is broken and due to the age of the OP, probably irrelevant.

Anyway, these days (March 2014) a popular, low-power computer is the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/).

It can be powered from USB, and even patch cables, but [there are some caveats](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs#powerHub). (Additional hardware required for patch cable power, for example.)

[image: logo]